# datetime set 1\1\1900 instead of Null or Blank

Tags: sql, sql-server

i HAVE datetime field when blank date value added it automatically set to `Jan  1 1900 12:00AM` or `1\1\1900` how can i avoid these.
Here is the code i used to update `[MOUNT DATE]` field

```
[MOUNT DATE] = 
CASE WHEN T1.[ROUTING]='L&P' then ''
END
ELSE T1.[A-MOUNT BY]
END

FROM WO T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WO#] = i.[WO#]
    END
```

Comment: is mountdate nullable?

Comment: Stop setting it to a blank space and set it to NULL instead.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn No, it allow null

Comment: @KenWhite that also does the same too

Comment: '' and NULL are different

Comment: No, it does not. Please post your schema definition (column data types). If you want help, provide the details we need to have in order to help you.

Comment: @KenWhite mybad its working now, i used NULL instead and working fine thank for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> instead of '' use NULL

```
[MOUNT DATE] = 
CASE WHEN T1.[ROUTING]='L&P' then NULL
END
ELSE T1.[A-MOUNT BY]
END

FROM WO T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WO#] = i.[WO#]
    END
```

test through this sample procedure

```
create table #temp1
(
mydate date null

)


insert #temp1 values (getdate())
select * from #temp1
update #temp1  set mydate = NULL
select * from #temp1

drop table  #temp1
```

Comment: *Try this* is a comment, not an answer. It shouldn't be posted as an answer unless you know it's the solution, and then you should explain **why** it's the answer.

Comment: i used the '' in an another trigger for the same field, now its working